# A static website on AWS not acccessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Somewhat curious about how to make a website on AWS, yesterday I went following this document:
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/host-static-website/?c_1
in order to get started with something simple.

I clicked the button `Get Started with the Implementation Guide` and found myself here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

It went pretty well, except that even today, I still can't acccess the site with the expected URL (http://example.com).
For the sake of simplicity I decided to leave alone http://www.example.com for the time being.

Since the `Step 2.5: Test Your Endpoint and Redirect` could be performed without any problem;
I suspect that something went wrong when performing `Step 3: Create and Configure Amazon Route 53 Hosted Zone`.

I did not find the explanations in the guide very clear, but I did what made sense to me, based on what I could see on the screen and on my previous experience in similar cases with other providers (other than AWS).

Anyone has tried this before and has something to point out?

For reference here is the kind of display I can see on Google Chrome:

```
This site can’t be reached
example.info’s server IP address could not be found.
Did you mean http://example.com/?
Search Google for example info
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Comment: start with this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html. Then you can work on the  custom domain (or just use a CNAME pointing to the bucket subdomain)

Comment: OK. The document looks nice but at the end it brings me back to exactly the same place I was (2nd URL mentioned in my post).

Comment: right but you should have a website being served from http://example-bucket.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com. Does that work?

Comment: Yes that works (as my post mentioned saying: Step 2.5: Test Your Endpoint and Redirect could be performed).

Comment: I also updated the NS records on the site holding the domain name. I know the replication can take some time. But in my previous experience it never took that long.

Answer (score 0):

In case something similar happens to someone else, here is what I did.
I finally solved the problem by following `Step 5: Route DNS Traffic for Your Domain to Your Website Bucket`
of this document:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/getting-started.html#getting-started-create-alias
 creating an Alias record.